libp11-kit.so.0:cannot open the shared object file:no such file or directory
ubuntu20.04
Maybe I remove some libp11-kit.so files,now I can't enter the ubuntu system. But I can enter grub and use recovery mode and boot. How can I enter ubuntu system correctly without losing my datas, please help me.

If you can execute commands in the recovery mode, then run the command sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop. Also try sudo apt install --reinstall   libp11-kit0

Without knowing what exactly you removed, it is a pure guesswork for us. If the commands I posted above do not work, please use a live USB to backup your data and reinstall Ubuntu. Also please do not delete system files like that.
